# How can I upload image with WYSIWYG editor on Yii extension?

Tags: yii, wysiwyg, yii-extensions

I want to know the way to upload image from my computer with WYSIWYG editor on Yii extension.

I have tried TinyMCE and other editor but I can't find the way to upload image from my computer. In my case, the image that will inserted to text area must be link, not the file. I want to know if there is a way to upload image from computer to WYSIWIG editor.

I would appreciate if there is an example to implement that case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CKeditor ([Ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)) with KCfinder([KCfinder](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/integrate)). There will be "select from server" button after integration. You can upload image right there and choose that one.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with tinymce , but maybe it can solve your problem.
Have you tried using this yii extension ?

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tinymceelfinder/

another options, you can use kindeditor. kindeditor allows to upload image.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-kindeditor/

hope this help.